# How can I configure Case Comment notifications to go to the Case Contact instead of the Portal User?

Tags: customer-portal, notification, servicecloud

Possible red herring, but this seems to coincide with the release of Spring '13. **On a Case record:**

1. if a support engineer clicks "Send an Email", an email is sent to the Case Contact's email. [good]
2. if a support engineer clicks "New Case Comment", an email is sent to the Portal User's email. [bad, last week it would be sent to the Case Contact's email.]

The new behaviour affecting 2. is problematic because the Portal User's email may not be the Case Contact's email. I recognize one is created from the other, but there are circumstances when they are out of sync:

- the customer changes their email address, we update the Contact but forget the Portal User,
- in Social Sign On implementations, where we don't want the user to have a username/password because they would be able to circumvent `Auth.RegistrationHandler.updateUser()`

Is the recipient of a Case Comment Notification configurable to use the Case Contact's email address?

Does best practise dictate keeping `Contact.Email` and `User.Email` in sync?

Comment: Certainly looks to be a bug, I've been impacted by it as well. We've dropped back to sending all emails from outlook until this can be cleared up - not the best solution for automation!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with amrcn_werewolf.

You can go into `Setup` -> `Create` -> `Workflow & Approvals` -> `Workflow Rules`.

- Click on `New Workflow Rule`
- Choose the Object you want the rule to be associated with (ex: Case Comment)
- Name the rule and give a description. I tried creating a rule where the field is Case Comment: Published equals True.
- Click `Save and Next`
- Add A workflow Action: `New Email Alert`
- Choose `Recipient Type Search: Related Contact`.
- Then once a new case comment is created it will go to the contact and the portal user

Comment: An anonymous user noted: That would be even better if it works. If you try this manipulation, you will see that when you apply a workflow to the object "case comment" the option "related contact" as recipient is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the built-in case comment notification system, did you consider creating a workflow with an email alert instead?  The email alert can be set to send only to the contact on the case.